# Can't figure out how to iterate through keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a context for the session of what I'm doing. Like so:

```
class Context
    CONTAINS = {}
end
```

I've been using it successfully like so:

```
Context::CONTAINS[:alpha] = "exampleA"
Context::CONTAINS[:beta] = "exampleB"
```

However `:alpha`might not contain anything some of the times the code runs. I was trying to iterate through it all by doing:

```
Context::CONTAINS.each { |x| puts x }
```

But that isn't working I get:

```
-:8:in `[]=': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

I can't figure out how to iterate through it to just retrieve the `:keys` that actually have something and use them.

Comment: how about `Context::CONTAINS.keys` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each_keys`. It's the ruby-way of doing it, though you can also use `each`

```
Context::CONTAINS.each_key { |k|
    puts k.to_s
}
```

`to_s` converts symbol to string.

`Context::CONTAINS.keys` is just another alias for `each_key`

Comment: Fun Ruby abuse: `puts Context::CONTAINS.keys.map(&:to_s)` ... which will puts an array, so whatever. :)